# How to create a k8s service account with a shorter token length?

Tags: kubernetes, passwords, kubernetes-dashboard

I’m using [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) and can log into it with a Service Account Token, which is created [according to the docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md).

[image: kubernetes dashboard login screen]

All works technically well and I can view my cluster resources as expected.
As a user of [Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/) for password management, I expect that I can store my token in the vault as a normal password and autofill it the next time I return to the Dashboard.
However, because of the [hard cap on password length in Bitwarden](https://github.com/bitwarden/server/issues/87), an attempt to store my token there fails:

[image: failing to save k8s token into Bitwarden vault]

Although the problem generally lies on the Bitwarden side, I’m wondering if it can be solved within Kubernetes. It would be great if it was possible to generate a Service Account with a *shorter* token if that’s theoretically allowed.

I tried editing my Service Account Secret by naively cutting the token in half, but the trick did not work – I started getting 401 response in the Dashboard Login form. Not a big surprise.

[image: editing service account token]

So my question is: how can one create a Service Account Token that would be, say, 500 characters long instead of about a thousand? Being able to do that can improve the user experience for me and other users of Bitwarden and should probably not affect cluster security too badly.

Comment: I believe that is not possible since it is encoded base64 token. You can try to use a external authentication method, like OAuth2, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens). It works for you?

Comment: Is the value of the token linked to anything? If I base64 decode it, trim a few chars, encode it again and save back to the secret, any change things can work? I’m not sure I can add OAuth2 to my cluster – that feels too complicated at this point :–)

Comment: It is a PEM key encoded and it uses bearer tokens to authenticate. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens)